# Socket.io Run in Webhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, web-hosting

Im currently new in setting up webhost server and Im studying socket.io and I would like to run it in live server, unfortunately it doesnt work. How do I set this up? I dont have a single Idea how.

It works in my local but not in webserver https://kimmychatroom.000webhostapp.com/

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Websocket 101</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mario-chat">
        <h2>Mario Chat</h2>
        <div id="chat-window">
            <div id="output"></div>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Handle" />
        <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
        <button id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**chat.js**

```
// make connection
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

//Query Dom

var message = document.getElementById('message'),
    handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
    btn = document.getElementById('send'),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat',{
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    })
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value)
});

// listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML +='<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
})

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message... </em></p>';
});
```

**index.js** EDITED

```
// install npm install nodemon -g
// run nodemon index to run server to gitbash
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQjiN8Qgs3c&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i4V-_ZVwLmOusj8YAUhj_9
// install socket.io - npm install socket.io --save


var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

// App setup
var app = express();

let port= process.env.PORT || 4000;
var server =  app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`listening to request on port ${port}`); 
});

// Static Files

app.use(express.static('public'));


// Socket setup

var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id)

    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    })

    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data)
    })
});
```

I dont have the slightest idea what to change in chat.js socket variable and index.js server variable

Answer (score 0):

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');` Here you should not provide the URL of the localhost while you deploy your application. While deploying you should use the URL or the webserver. Or if you are using the default namespace `/`, then there is no need of using a URL even in the localhost. Your code should be like this,

```js
//changes here
var socket = io()

//Query Dom
    var message = document.getElementById('message'),
    handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
    btn = document.getElementById('send'),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat',{
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    })
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value)
});

// listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML +='<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
})

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message... </em></p>';
});
```

Comment: how about the var server in index.js? should I not be changing that?

Comment: I think no problem with that. But it is better to change code like this, `var app = express();
let port=process.env.PORT||4000;
var server =  app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(``listening to request on port ${port}``);
});`Note:Put only one backtick inside console.log

Comment: i added your code but now im having error in my console https://mhistral.github.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NCjBQf8 404

Comment: this is the website https://mhistral.github.io/websockets-playlist/public_html/

Comment: now just try this, I am not sure if this works or not.`var io = socket(server,{transports:['websocket', 'polling']})` . The reason for this code is by default socket.io uses polling as transport first, then tries WebSockets, now this code changes the preferences as WebSocket first, later polling, because in your site polling causes the error.